# How to check purchase status on my server?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I know that we can use next code on device side:

```
licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["product"].IsActive
```

But I want to check purchase on my server. How can I do it?

Comment: I forgot specify platform: Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well, the new Windows Store APIs will be good for you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt609002.aspx

> If you have a catalog of apps and in-app products (IAPs), you can use
>   the Windows Store collection API and Windows Store purchase API to
>   access ownership information for these products from your services.

Comment: As I understood it'll work only for UWP. I forgot specify platform: Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1